# Should we be using time.sleep() or sleep()?

Tags: python, time, sleep

I have heard that using `sleep()` in python is more appropriate than using `time.sleep()`. If so, **why** and **where** is one more appropriate than the other one? (Is one more appropriate than the other or is it just the same? - without opinions - only fact.)

P.S. - Put `sleep()` or `time.sleep()` at the beginning of your answer so I know which one you have chosen.

Sleep:

```
 from time import sleep

 sleep(1)
```

Time sleep:

```
 time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: which python you are using ? where you get the function `sleep()` is this python 2 ?

Comment: They are equivalent; the former results from `from time import sleep`. Which you use is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @chepner I've been told that sleep() is more accurate that time.sleep(). I wanted to know if this is true or not.

Comment: @PythonMaster202 please put all your import statements in the question.

Comment: That depends on what you think `sleep` is. There is no function `sleep` aside from `time.sleep` in stock Python. Maybe whoever told you that was referring to a function imported from some other module.

Comment: @Chepner I've edited the question - sleep() is imported from time.

Comment: Then they are the exact same function. The only difference is the name/expression that refers to it. One is not faster than the other (though `sleep` is insignificantly faster to look up than `time.sleep`, because you don't have to go through an attribute lookup).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sleep() doesn't exist, except you do

```
from time import sleep
```

if you want to use `time.sleep()` you require following import

```
import time
```

at the beginning of the file

With above imports `time.sleep()` and `sleep()` are identical and I personally wouldn't say, that one is much more appropriate than the other.

However:

The advantage of
`from time import sleep`
is, that you could
replace this if you need with
`from myspecialmodule import sleep`
if you ever wanted to have another implementation of sleep.

and of course it is a little less typing in your code. (just `sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()`)

Just as a small side note 2022-08-16:

calling `sleep()` would be slightly faster than calling `time.sleep()`  as the python byte code would have to do one less symbol lookup.
In reality (except when being within a very tight performance critical loop) this will not be noticeable.
And in this particular context where you call a function, that should wait it wouldn't make any difference

Comment: your import statement contains a syntax error

Comment: If you do `from time import sleep`, you can't call `time.sleep`, that would result in `NameError: name 'time' is not defined`, only `sleep()` is valid - maybe you can restructure your sentence a bit.

Comment: yes. This was obvious for me, but perhaps better to say this explicitly in my answer. Do you think the answer is now easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` is not more accurate than `time.sleep`, because they are simply two different expressions referring to the same underlying function.